# Remove a dynamically added _parent_ div

Tags: javascript

I have a function which dynamically adds div, what i need is a button inside, which deletes **this** div. Eg: on click of a button, a div is added, with a button inside. On click of that button, the div is removed. Here's my code for addition of divs:

```
function newTextQuestion() {
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.style.borderLeft = "3px solid #00897b";
div.style.marginBottom = "20px";
div.style.paddingLeft = "10px";
div.style.backgroundColor = "white";

div.className = 'q';
div.setAttribute('data-type', '0');

var name = "random-" + parseInt(Math.random() * 1000000000);
div.innerHTML = '<h5>Tekstiküsimus:</h5><input class="text" name="' + name + '" type="text" placeholder="Küsimuse tekst..." oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(\'\See väli on kohustuslik!\'\)" oninput="setCustomValidity(\'\'\)" required>';
document.getElementById('questionnaireDiv').appendChild(div);

}
```

--- EDIT ---

What i've tried so far:

```
function newTextQuestion() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');

div.style.borderLeft = "3px solid #00897b";
div.style.marginBottom = "20px";
div.style.paddingLeft = "10px";
div.style.backgroundColor = "white";

var delbutton = document.createElement('button');
var delbuttontext = document.createElement('X');
delbutton.appendChild(delbuttontext);
delbutton.setAttribute("onclick", function() { $(this).parent().remove(); });

div.appendChild(delbutton);

div.className = 'q';
div.setAttribute('data-type', '0');

var name = "random-" + parseInt(Math.random() * 1000000000);
div.innerHTML = '<h5>Tekstiküsimus:</h5><input class="text" name="' + name + '" type="text" placeholder="Küsimuse tekst..." oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(\'\See väli on kohustuslik!\'\)" oninput="setCustomValidity(\'\'\)" required>';
    document.getElementById('questionnaireDiv').appendChild(div);

}
```

Comment: Hi :) Check the edit...

Answer (score 1):

When you need event handling capabilities, don't create an element via `.innerHTML`, use the `document.createElement()` technique. To create the button, just follow the same technique that you had already started.

Also, it's best to work with CSS classes when you can instead of setting individual properties.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('questionnaireDiv');
  
function newTextQuestion() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');

  div.classList.add("newDiv");
  div.classList.add("q");
  
  div.setAttribute('data-type', '0');

  var name = "random-" + parseInt(Math.random() * 1000000000);
  
  var h5 = document.createElement("h5");
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "text";
  input.classList.add("text");
  input.placeholder = "Küsimuse tekst...";
  input.required = true;
  
  input.addEventListener("invalid", function(){
    this.setCustomValidity("\'See väli on kohustuslik!\'");
  });
  
  input.addEventListener("input", function(){
    this.setCustomValidity("");
  });

  
  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.textContent = "Delete";

  div.appendChild(h5);
  div.appendChild(input);  
  div.appendChild(btn);
  
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    parent.removeChild(div);
  });
  parent.appendChild(div);
}

newTextQuestion();
```

```css
.newDiv {
  border-left: 3px solid #00897b;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color:"white";
}
```

```html
<div id="questionnaireDiv"></div>
```